# Restore a revision order

Tags: commerce

in a command I have the 1288 revision, 1498, 1499, 1500 I want to restore the 1288 revision and remove the 1498 revision, in 1499, 1500 can I do this in my database?

Thank you

Comment: Probably really difficult given all the factors involved in order state at various points in time. Also, rewriting the value in the database won't have the actual desired effect you seek.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the database *commerce_order* and *commerce_order_revision* I don't think order revision is implemented in a way that is revertible. Probably that is the reason we can't find revision revert functionality either in commerce core or as a contributed module.